# What's the replacement for REBASE.EXE?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, dll, rebase, winapi

I have a need to rebase the group of DLL files that I install with my program, because it's a 32-bit program and the address space is just too fragmented right now.  Also there is the problem of the entirety of the DLLs being demand-paged into RAM on a cold boot so that the loader can rebase them, due to base address conflicts with some DLLs.  Some DLLs are ones we have compiled; others are from 3rd parties.

What I would like to do is have a tool rebase a given set of DLLs so that the group of DLLs occupies a contiguous block of memory.  This tool would then be run just prior to the compilation of the setup program, and the rebased DLLs would be installed in the application's private directory.

From what I understand, the REBASE.EXE tool included with Windows SDK does/did exactly that.  Give it some DLLs, and it rebases them.

Unfortunately... [Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8 Consumer Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx) says:

> **Tools** Many obsolete or deprecated tools have been removed from the Windows SDK. The following tools have been removed:
>
> <snip> ReBase.exe

What now?  I don't want to start using a tool that is apparently obsolete and is going to go away in the next version of Windows.  Assuming I'm reading this right, what's the replacement for using ReBase.exe?  I would like to restrict myself to using tools that come with Windows SDK and/or Visual Studio, rather than introducing 3rd-party tools and/or writing my own rebase code.

Or, am I approaching this entire problem the wrong way?

Comment: You can carry on using rebase. It still works and it is not going to stop working.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It will stop working the moment we start using the Windows 8 SDK, according to that readme - because it won't be there, correct?

Comment: Also, I have not been able to find the documentation for REBASE.EXE on msdn.microsoft.com.  Any link for that?

Comment: You already have rebase.exe. You can use that on your DLLs that run on windows 8.

Comment: too bad there no verbose output like REBASE.EXE

Comment: Note: rebase.exe is also part of MSYS2/MSYS64 and from there also in Git bash (and cygwin) , you can possibly just use it from there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`editbin.exe` comes with VS2010 and has a /REBASE option.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>editbin
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Editor Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

usage: EDITBIN [options] [files]

   options:

      /ALLOWBIND[:NO]
      /ALLOWISOLATION[:NO]
      /BIND[:PATH=path]
      /DYNAMICBASE[:NO]
      /ERRORREPORT:{NONE|PROMPT|QUEUE|SEND}
      /HEAP:reserve[,commit]
      /LARGEADDRESSAWARE[:NO]
      /NOLOGO
      /NXCOMPAT[:NO]
      /REBASE[:[BASE=address][,BASEFILE][,DOWN]]
      /RELEASE
      /SECTION:name[=newname][,[[!]{CDEIKOMPRSUW}][A{1248PTSX}]]
      /STACK:reserve[,commit]
      /SUBSYSTEM:{BOOT_APPLICATION|CONSOLE|EFI_APPLICATION|
                  EFI_BOOT_SERVICE_DRIVER|EFI_ROM|EFI_RUNTIME_DRIVER|
                  NATIVE|POSIX|WINDOWS|WINDOWSCE}[,#[.##]]
      /SWAPRUN:{[!]CD|[!]NET}
      /TSAWARE[:NO]
      /VERSION:#[.#]
```

And as Mark points out you'll want to turn off ASLR, which you can do by using `/DYNAMICBASE:no`

Comment: EDITBIN /REBASE option does the trick nicely.  And MSDN shows that it has documentation for EDITBIN in Visual Studio 11, so I don't see them removing this anytime soon.  It's obvious why they are deprecating and removing REBASE.EXE from the Windows 8 SDK: it duplicates the functionality of EDITBIN!  I'm not sure why others think that the need to rebase is completely obsolete... - it's not.  Too bad a lot of the rebasing tutorials online still refer to REBASE.EXE...

Comment: too bad editbin doesn't generate verbose output like rebase.exe

Comment: also comes and works identical with VS2008

Answer (score 3):

The reason Rebase.exe is deprecated is that it's not as useful as it used to be. Starting with Windows Vista, Microsoft implemented [Address Space Layout Randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_and_safety_features_new_to_Windows_Vista#Preventing_exploits) which moves the system DLLs around every time you load them, and optionally the user DLLs as well.

If you're counting on rebasing to generate a large contiguous address space, you're going to be disappointed.

Comment: Some of our customers use Windows XP, which doesn't have ASLR.  The compiled DLLs are not ASLR-enabled, either - so they won't load with ASLR even on an ASLR operating system like Vista/7.  (I am not tampering with the system DLLs, which do lie in a reasonably contiguous space - even on Windows 7 with ASLR).

Comment: @James: If you're targeting Windows XP, a legacy/deprecated OS, then it makes perfect sense to use legacy/deprecated tools from the Windows SDK. That's what David is trying to tell you in the comments to the question.

Comment: This comment is very old, but for future visitors, @AdrianMcCarthy is incorrect. Consecutive's based DLLs are not guaranteed to load consecutively.

Comment: @MikeCaron I just saw the [blog entry by Raymond Chen](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170118-00/?p=95205) saying exactly that, is that what prompted you to leave the comment?

Comment: @MikeCaron:  Yeah, I just saw the recent Raymond Chen posts as well.  I'll delete my old comment so that it doesn't confuse anyone.

Answer (score 3):

Not to mention the use of "REBASE.EXE -b 0x58000000 -e 0x10000 -c coffbase.txt *.dll" against a set of files, simply to generate the COFFBASE file.
In other words not because you intend to actually rebase your files now, but because you want an accurate COFFBASE.TXT,
so that they will /already/ be built with a specific and non-conflicting base address every time they are built.