# rebase DLLs - is it really necessary to do it?

Tags: windows, performance, optimization, dll

Recently I learned about REBASE utility and that Microsoft runs it on all OS-supplied modules before shipping Windows.
As I understood, if relocating must be done by OS loader during app initialization, this not only impacts on startup time (for my system, I don't see any visible penalties), but also impacts on system performance.
I never did rebasing for DLLs before. Should I start to do it? I understand, that if I should, it would be only DLLs that come with my executable, not the system DLLs.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114492/whats-the-replacement-for-rebase-exe) I understood that REBASE is a deprecated utility.

Also, if rebasing is still relevant, how can I measure the performance improvement?

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969190/is-rebasing-dlls-or-providing-an-appropriate-default-load-address-worth-the-tr/4871945#4871945) explains why rebasing isn't worth the trouble